# how we can design imageView in corner of textView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

I am new in android so I am confuse in this design so please help me.
I want to design this type

[image]

Comment: yeah, its little confused design.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView)

### How to use

Add to your XML layout with your child views inside it:

```
<uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView
    android:id="@+id/ftv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/android"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dip"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/android2"/>
</uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>
```

### Then in your code:

```
    FlowTextView flowTextView = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.ftv);
    Spanned html = Html.fromHtml("<html>Your html goes here....");
    flowTextView.setText(html);
```

### Add the dependency:

> compile 'uk.co.deanwild:flowtextview:2.0.2'

Output:

[image]

Enjoy...

Comment: dependency is not working. An error is occur:- failed to resolved  compile 'com.github.deano2390:FlowTextView:2.0.5'

Comment: Try to use `compile 'uk.co.deanwild:flowtextview:2.0.2'`

You can use to find gradle dependency : http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#FlowTextView